# ”Classic” SQL query issue, how to avoid duplicates

Tags: sql

This query issue I have seen referred to in several places as a “classical SQL problem”. I have however not been able to find a solution. The problem is that I can´t find a way to avoid a duplicate in the result since Sam has the same speed in two heats.

Starting point is a chronological “Result” table from a competition:

```
Id  Name    Club        Engine      Class   Heat    Speed
1   Joe     NYRC        Rotax       Senior  1       320
2   Sam     GMRK        HQ          Senior  1       280
3   Adam    HCRC        Rossi       Senior  1       180
4   Rick    NYRC        Ford        Junior  1       220
5   Joe     NYRC        Rotax       Senior  2       330
6   Sam     GMRK        HQ          Senior  2       280
7   Adam    HCRC        Rossi       Senior  2       190
8   Joe     NYRC        Rotax       Senior  3       300
9   Sam     GMRK        HQ          Senior  3       210
10  Adam    HCRC        Rossi       Senior  3       200
```

What I want is a result list per class ordered after best result:

```
Pos Name    Club        Engine      Class   Heat    Speed
1   Joe     NYRC        Rotax       Senior  2       330
2   Sam     GMRK        HQ          Senior  1       280
3   Adam    HCRC        Rossi       Senior  3       200
```

What I am able to get:

```
Pos Name    Club        Engine      Class   Heat    Speed
1   Joe     NYRC        Rotax       Senior  2       330
2   Sam     GMRK        HQ          Senior  2       280
3   Sam     GMRK        HQ          Senior  1       280
4   Adam    HCRC        Rossi       Senior  3       200
```

Using the following query:

```
select yt.Name, yt.Club, yt.Engine, yt.Class, yt.Heat, yt.Speed
from Result yt
where Speed = (select max(Speed) from Result st where yt.Name=st.Name)
AND  Class = 'Senior'
Order by Speed DESC
```

Applying distinct somewhere seems to me a good idea but I have not been able to succeed!

Thanks for support

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want, but if you create an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with test data and desired results, it will be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: what platform are you using?

Comment: Heat have 2 different values, which value do you want to keep?

Comment: The lowest value.

Comment: I`m using SQL Server

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow Andy.  When using this site I suggest you consider being nice to the people who are helping you **for free**.  We are not your employees we are helping you as a **nice** act.  You might consider a tone which is also nice.

Comment: Really sorry Hogan if I wrote something that may have upset you, I´m not native in English so I´m not sure exactly what it can have been, but as I wrote : I´m really grateful for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Just get Max(speed) and group by every other field:

```
select yt.Name, yt.Club, yt.Engine, yt.Class, yt.Heat, max(yt.Speed) as MaxSpeed
from Result yt
where Class = 'Senior'
group by Name, Club, Engine, Class, Heat
Order by MaxSpeed DESC
```

Comment: I think he wants the row of the best result.

Comment: THis query gave all senior records in speed order.